# Migrate from struts to Angular8+Springboot - Third party SSO with cookies

Tags: angular, spring-boot, authentication, cookies, session-cookies

I have a MVC application written in Struts2.x which I am migrating to Angular8 and Spring boot.
Currently, the authentication mechanism is done using cookies.
So :

1. The user logs into the browser, the flow goes into the loginAction, starts a session and checks for any cookies.
2. If cookies are not available, then the code is redirected from my JSP to a third party URL page something like: http://auth.thirdparty.com/pageLogin/?retURL=/myapp/loginforward.jsp&systName=my_app
3. The user logs in on a the third party window and after successfully logging in is redirected to my app’s “/myapp/loginforward.jsp”. Only this time, a cookie is returned along with it which has the user details. The code in my struts app uses a library provided by that third-party to decode the cookie info and maintain it in the session.
4. This is the third party apps SingleSignOn mechanism and any other app using the same third party sso and opened in the same browser window is automatically logged in.

How do I translate this mechanism between my Angular and Springboot app, since the back end rest api ideally should be “stateless” ? I don’t see a way to implement oauth here.
How do I maintain a session and security, given the scenario, between angular and springboot? What should the flow be like?